# Django with MySQL deploy on aws ec2

Tags: django, python-2.7, nginx, gunicorn

I want to deploy my django with MySQL db for production on aws ec2. Files and db are present on the server.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: What do you mean, the db is present on the server? A MySQL database does not come as a file you can deploy.

Comment: @opalczynski how to deploy it for production?

Comment: @DanielRoseman MySQL database is already setup on the ec2 instance. I'm able to runserver, but I'm unable to deploy for production.

Comment: OK, but what does "deploy it for production" mean and how are you "unable" to do it? What did you do, what happened, and how did that differ from what you expect?

Comment: Actually - you have two options. Use AWS RDS is first (recommended) - it is pretty simple - you need to create a mysql RDS in Amazon Console; then store the credentials and host/port - and use this in you application settings. You must be careful with AWS security groups - because it can be possible that you will need to add additional rule - to make nodes see each other. The second option is to - install mysql manually on the same node - but this is far from 'production'. RDS gives you a lot of options: backups; scaling; multiple zone availability, etc.

Comment: http://agiliq.com/blog/2014/08/deploying-a-django-app-on-amazon-ec2-instance/  
I followed instructions from this page. But didn't work.

Comment: Any errors? Console logs?

Answer (score 0):

follow the official docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html, start directly at "Configure Your Django Application for Elastic Beanstalk", since you have already developed your app